# No puedo poner un botón encima de un input con z-index tailwind

Tags: html, tailwind

Estoy utilizando Tailwind. Tengo un input donde quiero poner un botón encima a la derecha y el botón puesto, pero no puedo hacerle click, he intentando poniéndole z-index, pero no hace nada y sigo sin poder hacer click

Anexo el input:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm" style="position:relative; z-index: 4;">
    <input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete"
        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
        placeholder="Escribe algo para buscar">
    <div class="z-50 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 pr-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none"
        style="position:absolute; z-index: 9;">
        <button id="clearSearch" style="position:relative; z-index: 10;">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#6b7280">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                    d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo causa la clase `pointer-events-none` que colocaste en el `div` que contiene al botón. Si quitas esa clase, el botón funcionará normalmente.

La propiedad CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) indica si el elemento (el DIV) y su contenido deben responder a eventos del ratón, si le asignas el valor `none` no va a reaccionar al clic u otros eventos del ratón.

Comment: gracias! ahora tengo otro problema, cómo podría evitar que al poner mucho texto, este se ponga por debajo del botón borrar? en el ejemplo de la pregunta al escribir mucho texto en el input, el texto se pone debajo del botón

Comment: ya logré solucionarlo con esta clase en el input focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full pr-10 sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md

Answer (score 1):

Amigo no se mucho de Tailwind, pero como te mencionan el error lo causa la propiedad pointer-events-none, basta con saber ingles y detallar bien el código. Así ya debería funcionar.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm" style="position:relative; z-index: 4;">
    <input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete"
        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
        placeholder="Escribe algo para buscar">
    <div class="z-50 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 pr-3 flex items-center"
        style="position:absolute; z-index: 9;">
        <button id="clearSearch" style="position:relative; z-index: 10;">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#6b7280">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                    d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```